# Airflow: restrict viewing of user dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

im using Airflow:2.5.3

I have assigned subfolders for each user inside the dags folder of airflow

```
dags/
├── dag-user1/
│   ├── dag_a.py
|   ├── dag_b.py
├── dag-user2/
|   ├── dag_c.py
|   ├── dag_d.py
├── dag-user3/
|   ├── dag_e.py
|   ├── dag_f.py
```

what I am trying to do is that in the airflow GUI the user can only see the dags that are in his own subfolder, currently all users see all dags.

I have tried to assign roles to the users but I have seen that the roles are assigned to the dags but not to the subfolders.

Is it possible to do that or is that how airflow is supposed to work?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official documentation for DAG level access control.

[Here is the particular area that is relevant to your needs.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/security/access-control.html#dag-level-permissions)